# How can I center form content in a Bootstrap container?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, positioning

It looks great on a mobile device, but when the site is rendered in larger screen size, as can be seen from the attached image, the main form content (everything `#form_content`) is aligned to the left of center.

[image]

I have tried placing such attributes as `'justify-content-center'`, `'align-items-center'` `'mx-auto'` in various `divs` and just cannot get that content to move into the middle of the larger screen!

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="p-5 container-fluid text-center" id="banner">
  <h1 class="display-1" id="title">Contact Us</h1>
  <img src="images/marine_divider1_lmbc_red.png" id="wheel" alt="divider"><br>
</div>

<section id="contact">
  <div class="container-fluid col-md-6 mx-auto mt-3 ">
    <form class="form" name="form" autocomplete="off" action="https://formsubmit.co/troy_a_w_easson@outlook.com" method="POST">

      <div class="mb-3" id="form_box">
        <label class="form-label" for="name" style="color: black; margin-bottom: 0px;">Name:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" name="name" required style="max-width: 500px; margin-top: 0px;">
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3" id="form_box">
        <label class="form-label" for="email" style="color: black; margin-bottom: 0px">Email Address:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" placeholder="e.g. name@example.com" name="email" required style="max-width: 500px; margin-top: 0px;">
        <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else without your permission.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-5" id="form_box">
        <label class="form-label" for="subject" style="color: black; margin-bottom: 0px">Subject:</label>
        <input class="form-control mb-2" id="subject" type="text" name="subject" style="max-width: 500px; margin-top: 0px;">
      </div>

      <div class="form-floating mb-5" id="form_box">
        <textarea id="query" class="form-control" name="message" spellcheck="true" style="height: 250px; overflow-y: visible; max-width: 500px"></textarea>
        <label for="query" class="textlab">Type your message here: <span class="tooltip" data-tooltip="Type your message here">?</span></label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-floating mb-5" id="form_box">
        <textarea id="query" class="form-control" name="mark" spellcheck="true" style="height: 100px; max-width: 500px"></textarea>
        <label for="query" class="textlab">How did you hear about us?<span class="tooltip" data-tooltip="Just a few words on how you found our website and heard about our club">?</span></label>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-5 text text-center">
        <button type="submit" id="conbtn" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">Send Now!</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="container text-center mx-auto">
      <img src="images/controllertransp.png" id="controller" alt="divider"><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Here is the relevant external CSS I've used in this section:

```
section {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change the HTML? The biggest problem is that your `section` isn't a flex parent, so none of those properties (`justify-content`, `align-`, etc) will affect the children elements.

What you might want to consider is adding the `row` element inside of the `container-fluid` along with using the `col` classes to wrap the form.

The other concern is that your form fields (`.form-control` input elements) have a `max-width` set using inline styles, so on larger screens they may not appear centered, since they will be shorter in width than the containing `col` element.

You can remove that inline style (if it's not needed) to achieve a centered look. I put in custom CSS to set the `max-width: none !important` to show the affect of removing the inline style.

```css
.form-control {
  max-width: none !important/* override the inline style */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="p-5 container-fluid text-center" id="banner">
  <h1 class="display-1" id="title">Contact Us</h1>
  <img src="images/marine_divider1_lmbc_red.png" id="wheel" alt="divider"><br>
</div>

<section id="contact">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- added this -->
    <div class="row">
      <!-- added this  the offset class adds the margin left the equivalent of the columns -->
      <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-lg-4 offset-lg-4">
        <form class="form" name="form" autocomplete="off" action="https://formsubmit.co/troy_a_w_easson@outlook.com" method="POST">

          <div class="mb-3" id="form_box">
            <label class="form-label" for="name" style="color: black; margin-bottom: 0px;">Name:</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" name="name" required style="max-width: 500px; margin-top: 0px;">
          </div>

          <div class="mb-3" id="form_box">
            <label class="form-label" for="email" style="color: black; margin-bottom: 0px">Email Address:</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" placeholder="e.g. name@example.com" name="email" required style="max-width: 500px; margin-top: 0px;">
            <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else without your permission.</div>
          </div>

          <div class="mb-5" id="form_box">
            <label class="form-label" for="subject" style="color: black; margin-bottom: 0px">Subject:</label>
            <input class="form-control mb-2" id="subject" type="text" name="subject" style="max-width: 500px; margin-top: 0px;">
          </div>

          <div class="form-floating mb-5" id="form_box">
            <textarea id="query" class="form-control" name="message" spellcheck="true" style="height: 250px; overflow-y: visible; max-width: 500px"></textarea>
            <label for="query" class="textlab">Type your message here: <span class="tooltip" data-tooltip="Type your message here">?</span></label>
          </div>

          <div class="form-floating mb-5" id="form_box">
            <textarea id="query" class="form-control" name="mark" spellcheck="true" style="height: 100px; max-width: 500px"></textarea>
            <label for="query" class="textlab">How did you hear about us?<span class="tooltip" data-tooltip="Just a few words on how you found our website and heard about our club">?</span></label>
          </div>

          <div class="mb-5 text text-center">
            <button type="submit" id="conbtn" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">Send Now!</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="container text-center mx-auto">
          <img src="images/controllertransp.png" id="controller" alt="divider"><br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank ye, kind sire!  I added, exactly that which you recommended, and it appears to have corrected the problem.

Comment: Also, I am indeed happy to edit the HTML if needbe, especially with regard to cleaner code, therefore if you have any further suggestions on this front, i am all eyes!

Answer (score 0):

You can try uisng single container for whole form and other elements on the page. This will help center all your content.

Comment: You should copy the snippet down here and demonstrate your solution. It lacks detail. See [answer].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).